# How to break a Json var into specific formate in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am retrieving values from database and parsing it into JSON .My JSON data formate is like..

```
[{"INCOMING":"09:09:49","INETCALL":"00:14:09","ISD":"00:05:50","LOCAL":"02:38:02","STD":"01:39:28"}]
```

I want to break this JSON value into two variables one is:

```
var toc=["INCOMING","INETCALL","ISD","LOCAL","STD"]
```

and the other variable like this..

```
var callduration=["09:09:49","00:14:09","00:05:50","02:38:0","01:39:28"]
```

Now as per my need i have to break it into two variables for that i have written a for loop but it is not working .Here is my Client side code..

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getdataduration',
                async:false,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data);
                    var dbdata=JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(dbdata);
                    for(var i=0,len=dbdata.length;i<len;i++){
                        $.isNumeric(dbdata[i]) ?  callduration.push(dbdata[i]) :  toc.push(dbdata[i]);
                    }

                }

            });

            console.log(toc);
            console.log(callduration);
```

Please guys help me .
Thanks in advance..

Comment: `dbdata[i]` is an object, so have no idea what you are trying to test with `$.isNumeric`.Code that doesn't work is not a substitute for an explanation of what the code should do

Comment: how are you trying to get that broken up?

Comment: @charlietfl i updated my post .pLease check sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would work witih that...

```
var data = [{"INCOMING":"09:09:49","INETCALL":"00:14:09","ISD":"00:05:50","LOCAL":"02:38:02","STD":"01:39:28"}];

console.log(data); 

console.log( data[0].INCOMING );     // 09:09:49 
console.log( data[0]['INCOMING'] );  // 09:09:49 

var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

console.log(keys);    // ["INCOMING", "INETCALL", "ISD", "LOCAL", "STD"] 


var values = [];
var keys   = [];

$.each(data,function(i,val){
   console.log(val);     // Object {INCOMING: "09:09:49", INETCALL: "00:14:09", ISD: "00:05:50", LOCAL: "02:38:02", STD: "01:39:28"} 

   $.each(val,function(key2,val2){
      console.log(key2 + " = " + val2); 

      keys.push(key2); 
      values.push(val2); 

      // INCOMING = 09:09:49  
      // INETCALL = 00:14:09 
      // ISD = 00:05:50 
      // LOCAL = 02:38:02  
      // STD = 01:39:28  
   }); 
});

console.log(keys);     // ["INCOMING", "INETCALL", "ISD", "LOCAL", "STD"] 
console.log(values);   // ["09:09:49", "00:14:09", "00:05:50", "02:38:02", "01:39:28"]
```

Comment: Thank u sir for ur support .I have one doubt if want to show values as [09:09:49, 00:14:09, 00:05:50, 02:38:02, 01:39:28] then how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 $(function(){

     var toc = [];
     var callduration =[];
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'getdataduration',
         async:false,
         dataType: "text",
         success: function(data) {
          //   console.log(data);
             var dbdata=JSON.parse(data);
            // console.log(dbdata);                
            $.each(dbdata[0], function(key, value){
                console.log(key, value);
                toc.push(key);
                callduration.push(value)
            });                            

         }

     });

     console.log(toc);
     console.log(callduration);

 });
```

**Output Console:**

```
   ["INCOMING", "INETCALL", "ISD", "LOCAL", "STD"]

   ["09:09:49", "00:14:09", "00:05:50", "02:38:02", "01:39:28"]
```